# Can we set CacheSize in MB for the MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have MongoDB Replication Setup and have 1800 MB of RAM out of which 1100 MB is utilising and in that also there is 600 MB cache.So I got the configuration parameter for "CacheSize" on MongoDB but for 1 GB.

So can I keep the cache size in MB, If yes then what the Minimum RAM I can keep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB) cacheSizeGB values can range from 0.25 GB to 10000 GB.

Comment: Thank you, Means According to the Doc I can't Use the MB but in GB I can use 0.25 or whatever the value I want Right?